# Updating table rows in while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update all rows of ids in table. So I have written below query to update it using while loop as shown below -

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT,@WhereCond INT
SET @intFlag = 49990609
SET @WhereCond = 49973348
WHILE (@WhereCond <=50038355)
BEGIN
    update stf_firm_fin_trans_backup set stf_fft_id = @intFlag where stf_fft_id = @WhereCond
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    SET @WhereCond = @WhereCond + 1

END
GO
```

But somehow after running above query `stf_fft_id` column is showing duplicate records. Ideally is should have duplicate record because `@intFlag` and `@WhereCond` is incremented by 1 in each iteration.

Any suggestion why it is happening and how to avoid?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A `while` loop is almost certainly not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
WITH toupdate as
      SELECT TOP (50038355 - 49973348) b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stf_fft_id) as seqnum
      FROM stf_firm_fin_trans_backup
      WHERE stf_fft_id >= 49973348
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET stf_fft_id = 49990609 + seqnum;
```

I don't know if this will fix your duplicate key problem, but the code will run faster.